# HTML Dropdown Value changing on Page Refresh

Tags: html, firefox, select

Ok, so this is a wierd one and have not seen it before.

I have a simple html dropdown w/ no js attached (yet).

This is using html4(xhtml1?) with transitional doctype.
btw.. i tried with escaping slashes and without, same results. (/)

```
<select id="myDropdown" name="myDropdown">
<option value="option1" selected="selected">Contact &#x2F; Email Customer Care</option>
<option value="option2">Group &#x2F; Private Tour</option>
<option value="option3">Option3</option>
<option value="option4">Option4</option>
<option value="option5">Option5</option>
</select>
```

When I do a hard reload (ctrl+f5, or ctrl+shift+R)  It loads the correct option in the box (option 1).

However, if I hit just plain F5 for a soft refresh, it loads option2 as the selected option ONLY if option 1 is selected.   If option 3, 4 or 5 are selected, it doesn't change.   But if option 1 is selected,  it changes to option 2 every time on a page refresh.

Any ideas why this is happening?  It's extremely frustrating and I don't see anything about it online.

Thanks

Comment: which browser? on Safari and Chrome (both on OSX) I wasn't able to repro this

Comment: good point, apparently this is only an issue w/ firefox

Comment: Why can't I edit my own post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a strange Firefox behavior, I can see it in versions of Firefox up to and including 27 (current). I'd suggest logging a bug/sending feedback.

to solve the issue though is fairly simple... if you want the drop-down to always reset on a page load just a simple bit of script after the combo will force that (and doesn't have a negative impact on other browsers

```
<script>
// console.log(document.getElementById("myDropdown").value)
document.getElementById("myDropdown").selectedIndex = 0
</script>
```

if the selected value is likely to change, then you'll want the `selectedIndex` to match whatever value you're adjusting the `selected` to indicate.

Oh, and just a note on the `selected="selected"` ... that attribute would usually be just `selected` but

```
<option value="option1" selected>Contact &#x2F; Email Customer Care</option>
```

doesn't make a difference here

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I knew I could use JS but was wondering why in the world it was doing that.   IF its just a FF bug tho, that will hopefully go away eventually.  I don't know how to do all the bug logging, etc.. .    Question on the "selected", is that for html5?  or just html4?  I know xhtml1 is selected="selected"

Comment: BTW even if i completely remove the selected="selected" the same behavior results.

Comment: I have added a reference to this to Bugzilla [https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=632351] but as it's been open since 2011 I suspect you'll need the JS from above to fix it for a while yet ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, wish I could give you more points.  You are very knowledgeable.

Comment: All good... SO is all about helping where you can, and learning

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as in the [answer by Offbeatmammal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21668260/4669135) but a bit more automated, assuming that you can use the same attribute on all the selectors in the page (else restrict using a class or id):

```
<script>
function fix_selectors_positions()
{
    selectors = document.querySelectorAll("select");
    selectors.forEach(item =>
        item.selectedIndex = item.getAttribute("default_pos")
    );
}
window.onload = fix_selectors_positions;
</script>
```

And then use the attribute default_pos on the selectors:

```
<select default_pos="0">[...]
```